# Message queue behavior in QuickFIX/J for disconnected clients

Tags: java, session, quickfix, quickfixj

I wanted to clarify a behavior of `QuickFIX/J` (FIX 4.2) under the following scenario. There are two parties involved in this `QuickFIX/J` communication:

1. A client initiator, called **I**.
2. Our firm's acceptor program, called **A**.

When **I** logs onto **A**, they exchange FIX messages with tag `35=A`. Once a connection is established, **I** starts to submit orders. There may be a point however, where **I** disconnects unexpectedly, at which point **A** decides to send cancels for all of the open orders of **I** (this is valid, because **A** has no idea why **I** failed or when **I** would come back alive).

Note that this entire cancel-on-disconnect procedure is initiated and handled by **A** alone - it gets initiated from **A**'s `onLogout(...)` method and handled by its normal order management mechanisms. A single `35=F` message gets generated for each of the open orders of **I**, and an `ExecutionReport` (`35=8`) gets generated on each successful cancel.

When **I** comes back alive, these `ExecutionReport`s must be delivered to **I** somehow so that it becomes aware all its previous orders have been cancelled. I had an impression that `QuickFIX/J`'s message queue implementation handles this without an application-level aid. All `QuickFIX` messages are ensured for delivery to counter-parties (http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.finance.quickfix.devel/169).

Contrary to my understanding, however, no `ExecutionReport`s were not shown in **A**'s `QuickFIX` logs, or delivered to **I** when **I** reconnected, resulting **I** to be unaware that its previous orders have been cancelled. I noticed that logging does not occur because of the following source code of the `sendRaw(Message message, int num)` method of `Session` in `QuickFIX/J`:

```
/**
 * Send the message
 *
 * @param message is the message to send
 * @param num is the seq num of the message to send, if 0, the next expected sender seqnum is used.
 * @return
 */
private boolean sendRaw(Message message, int num) {
    ...
        } else {
            try {
                application.toApp(message, sessionID);
            } catch (final DoNotSend e) {
                return false;
            } catch (final Throwable t) {
                logApplicationException("toApp()", t);
            }
            messageString = message.toString();
            if (isLoggedOn()) { // happens only if session is connected
                result = send(messageString); // logging happens within "send"
            }
        }
    ...
}
```

The session was not logged on while `ExecutionReport` messages were being generated for cancels initiated by **I**'s disconnect, and therefore it never hit the `send(messageString);` and no logging happened. I believe no message got queued (based on the fact that **I** does not receive any messages when it comes back alive) for the same reason.

Our firm made many implementations based on the belief that `QuickFIX/J` guarantees all messages to be delivered without a loss, but my observation on the scenario above speaks otherwise.

How is `QuickFIX/J`'s message queue expected to behave in this scenario, when a session is not logged on? Should it queue messages regardless, waiting to be sent once the session becomes available again in the future, or stop queuing for the duration while the session is down?

Comment: You may want to try the QF/j mailing list for this one, if nobody here answers.

Comment: "There may be a point, however, where I disconnects unexpectedly, at which point A decides to send cancels for all of the open orders of I[...]". That sounds terrible. Simply because there is a network problem eg for 15 minutes, you cancel all orders??? Sorry to say so, but that sounds ridiculous. What rationale is there behind that? What real business explanation is there for that requirement?

Comment: @GrantBirchmeier Thanks for the feedback. We actually confirmed that `35=8` and `150=4` was coming to the initiator from the acceptor upon reconnect. I somehow failed to detect that.

Comment: @TT. I believe the rationale is that the practice reduces the risk of executing orders that are no longer wanted - during a network issue, client might try to cancel or replace a currently-open order and that obviously cannot go through. Of course, cancelling all open orders in case of unexpected failure is not ideal for everyone, but it does provide a guard against some scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just at the end of the `private boolean sendRaw(Message message, int num)` method there is this code:

```
if (num == 0) {
    final int msgSeqNum = header.getInt(MsgSeqNum.FIELD);
    if (persistMessages) {
        state.set(msgSeqNum, messageString);
    }
    state.incrNextSenderMsgSeqNum();
}
```

The `state.set(msgSeqNum, messageString)` will call `messageStore.set(sequence, message)` which actually stores the message for later delivery if the session is not connected.

As far as I know, all messages will be queued until the session successfully logs on.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my 10 cents: When QF/J guarantees message delivery that's for active sessions, based on the sequence numbers, and gap fills...

If a session is lost there's no way to guarantee anything. What you have to do is configure your initiator and acceptor to gap fill on reconnect, once a sequence number mismatch is discovered. Hmm, what does your ResetOnDisconnect flag say in the config? How about ResetOnLogout?

I don't think there's a "queue" of messages waiting for sessions in QF, because a session could disco and never recon meaning the QF queue just kept filling, or was active forever, which is not something QF is going to be able to handle out of the box for everyone.

If you have a disco, neither can you use OnLogout to send execution reports to the disconnected client! First of all OnLogout isn't always called on every disco, and secondly as you say we get into the QF internals and it can't find a session to send a message to so it excepts. I wouldn't expect the QF internal queue to handle this situation for me. Again, the guaranteed delivery is when the connection is UP... That's a dependency. However, I *would* expect it to be logged somewhere. What's your logging config?

I think you need to look at why: *"When / comes back alive, these ExecutionReports must be delivered to / somehow so that it becomes aware all its previous orders have been cancelled."* isn't the process more that on disco all orders are taken to have been cancelled? Why does / need confirmation of that? It's a given, no? This may be something you have to code up separately to the QF base.

Comment: CancelOnDisconnect is a flag I have heard of somewhere :)

Comment: "Why does / need confirmation of that?" We think it would be useful for future implementations where we give our clients an option to cancel open orders on disconnect (and also not to cancel). Also, it is generally safe to exchange these confirmations because the cancel might have not initiated properly by the firm for some reason. Anyways, I was missing something back then, and now know that `35=8` with `150=4` gets sent to the client on reconnect.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](http://www.fixtradingcommunity.org/pg/discussions/topicpost/169933/cod-typical-values).

Some companies support the tag `35002` (Cancel on Disconnect) in the `LOGON` message, with possible values:

- 0: Do not use COD
- 1: Use COD only when a "graceful" logout is sent
- 2: Use COD on any "network" disconnection
- 3: 1 AND 2

Find out if your counterparty supports this. I haven't checked QuickFIX support but you can always add the tag yourself manually, or customize your FIX dictionary to support the tag.

Apparantly this is often used by High Frequency Traders. I am not familiar with that industry, hence the question in comments section.